# how to uninstall all packages installed by "aptitude build-dep"

Tags: aptitude

Is it possible to undo all changes made by "aptitude build-dep xxxxxx" i.e to un-install all dependencies installed by this command?

Comment: Remove the program (for which you installed dependencies) and the type `sudo apt-get autoremove` . this might work.

Comment: @Ashu: No, it doesnt. Already tried it.

Comment: try this `apt-cache depends PACKAGE_NAME` this will print all the packages needed by a program and the uninstall whatever you think is not needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an automatic way. Packages installed through `build-dep` are recorded in the same way as if they'd been directly requested by name.

If you know approximately when you ran `aptitude build-dep`, you can find which packages got installed when you ran the command by looking through the logs in `/var/log/aptitude*` or `/var/log/apt/*`.

You can run `apt-cache showsrc PACKAGENAME | grep '^Build-depends:'` to list the build dependencies of the package. Review each of them to see if you want them; mark the ones you don't care about as not manually installed (`apt-get markauto PACKAGENAME`) and flush the non-required packages (`apt-get autoremove`).

Answer (score 9):

For the future, I highly recommend using `mk-build-deps -i` instead of `aptitude build-dep`. That leaves a package installed in your system, depending on the build-deps, that you can easily uninstall later.

Answer (score 4):

I found these commands on a Launchpad [question](https://answers.launchpad.net/apt/+question/8366):

```
sudo aptitude markauto $(apt-cache showsrc PACKAGE_NAME | grep Build-Depends | perl -p -e 's/(?:[\[(].+?[\])]|Build-Depends:|,|\|)//g')
```

There is also an alternative based around sed that copes with brackets in package names:

```
sudo aptitude markauto $(apt-cache showsrc PACKAGE_NAME | sed -e '/Build-Depends/!d;s/Build-Depends: \|,\|([^)]*),*\|\[[^]]*\]//g')
```

*Note: Replace `PACKAGE_NAME` with your own package.*