# How can I remove all build dependencies for a particular package?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

When I want to compile something from source in Ubuntu/Debian, I usually get build-dependencies by running "`sudo apt-get build-dep PACKAGE_NAME`" in the terminal.

They are (usually) useless once the compilation job is done.

So, how do I remove all **build-dependencies** for a particular package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find out the build-dependencies of a program you can run `apt-cache showsrc pkgname` and that will list, amongst other information the `Build-Depends`, which are often files ending in `-dev`; although it is worth checking if any of the files (particularly those not marked `-dev`) are required by other programs. You could find this out by using `apt-cache depends file` and `apt-cache rdepends file`. The following example is for `Shotwell`:

```
apt-cache showsrc shotwell
```

> Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.50~), m4, valac-0.16 (>= 0.15), libgee-dev (>= 0.5.0), libgtk-3-dev (>= 3.0.11), libexif-dev (>= 0.6.16), libsqlite3-dev (>= 3.5.9), libgexiv2-dev (>= 0.4.1-1build1), libgnomevfs2-dev (>= 2.24.2), libgphoto2-2-dev (>= 2.4.2), libsoup2.4-dev (>= 2.26.0), libxml2 (>= 2.6.32), libunique-3.0-dev (>= 1.0.0), libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev (>= 1.1.5), libgudev-1.0-dev (>= 145), libdbus-glib-1-dev (>= 0.80), libraw-dev (>= 0.13.1-2), libusb-dev, libjson-glib-dev (>= 0.7.6), libgstreamer0.10-dev (>= 0.10.28), libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev (>= 0.10.32), python-scour, libunity-dev, liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-dev (>= 0.1.36), librest-dev

There is a command to do it all in one go at [the webupd8 site](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/undo-apt-get-build-dep-remove-build.html), **but** I have found that it doesn't seem to work reliably with the current version of Ubuntu in that it seems to **remove** too much. I tried it with Pinta and it suggested removing the entire mono library. There is discussion of such problems with using commands like the webupd8 one at [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/apt/+question/8366). Be very careful when experimenting with any 'solutions' you might find.

It is a shame that there is no `autoremove` command for `build-dep` installed packages.

Comment: I tried aptitude method & yes, you are right , it removes too much...may because of cross-dependencies. One another mothod i found is to pass the following option (while using build-dep command): `sudo apt-get build-dep -o APT::Get::Build-Dep-Automatic=true PACKAGE_NAME`. Now they can be removed with `apt-get autoremove`. But this works only after removing the main package.

Comment: Anyway, I just learned that the proper-way to do it, is using `pbuilder`. So no-one has to worry about installing/uninstalling dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

Tumbleweed [writes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140835/how-to-uninstall-all-packages-installed-by-aptitude-build-dep#146562):

> For the future, I highly recommend using `mk-build-deps` ... instead of `aptitude build-dep`. That leaves a package ... in your system, [which has dependencies] on the build-deps, that you can easily uninstall later.

[`mk-build-deps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mk-build-deps.1.html) can be installed with `sudo apt install devscripts`

Comment: Note that you may also need to run `sudo apt install equivs` because `devscripts` only `Suggests` that package and it's actually *required* to execute `mk-build-deps`.

Answer (score 4):

### **Option 1:**

Remember which packages were installed by `sudo apt-get build-dep PACKAGE_NAME` and remove them after building.

### **Option 2:**

`apt-cache showsrc` gives a great deal of information about source packages, including a list of build-depends.

```
apt-cache showsrc PACKAGE_NAME
```

For example:

```
$ apt-cache showsrc pithos
Package: pithos
Binary: pithos
Version: 0.3.17~git07dcbd86a1
Section: python
Maintainer: Kevin Mehall <km@kevinmehall.net>
Build-Depends: cdbs (>= 0.4.43), debhelper (>= 6), python, python-central (>= 0.6.11), python-distutils-extra (>= 2.10)
Architecture: all
Standards-Version: 3.8.2
Format: 1.0
Directory: pool/main/p/pithos
Files:
 cdf2129923e62bb62c246965453b40bd 2023031 pithos_0.3.17~git07dcbd86a1.tar.gz
 97689e8ada8be527d689f2c83415d3b0 1544 pithos_0.3.17~git07dcbd86a1.dsc
Python-Version: current
Checksums-Sha1: 35cbf3ae52922e50a0b81afcce2cd97a86afb254 2023031 pithos_0.3.17~git07dcbd86a1.tar.gz
Package-List: pithos deb python extra
Checksums-Sha256: 2b704d86f3dc1d36d180177d11e578bdcf74ea97b09b530144afe754e570b262 2023031 pithos_0.3.17~git07dcbd86a1.tar.gz
$ sudo apt-get remove cdbs debhelper python python-central python-distutils-extra
```

The risk with this option is that you may remove a package that is important for something *besides* building PACKAGE_NAME. Just read through the list of packages to be removed before going ahead.

Answer (score 4):

So that packages you need don't get removed:

```
read -p "Enter package name: " packageName
sudo apt-mark auto $(apt-cache showsrc $packageName | sed -e '/Build-Depends/!d;s/Build-Depends: \|,\|([^)]*),*\|\[[^]]*\]//g' | sed -E 's/\|//g; s/<.*>//g')
sudo apt-mark manual build-essential fakeroot devscripts
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

However, you really should consider using `mk-build-deps` in the future to avoid this package trainwreck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/var/log/apt/history.log` for this. Use `grep` to find the correct line and pass the cleaned up list of packages to `apt remove`:

```
 apt remove $(cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "Install: fontconf" | sed -re 's/\([^)]+\)//g' -re 's/:[^ ]+//g' -re 's/, //g' -re 's/^Install: //g')
```

This example was used to remove packages from a `apt build-dep linux`.

Check the packages listed in apt the remove operation carefully.

Execute also a `apt autoremove`, just in case.

Comment: this is a good method to clean up the mess, in combination with `apt-mark auto` from [jack's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259132/52041).