# How to uninstall Emacs file?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I'm trying to install Emacs for my ubuntu 16.04.1 using the steps mention in [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/emacs-24-4-released-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/) link but at step 4 I got an error but there is some emacs file already installed in my system. When I run `sudo apt-cache search emacs` there is file showing under these.

So I want to remove those file.  I found this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove `apt-cache search emacs | awk '{print $1}' --purge
```

That doesn't work. So please help.

Comment: 16.04 has [emacs 24.5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/emacs24), so why are you following that guide instead of doing just `sudo apt-get install emacs24`?

Comment: If you only got to Step 4 of that guide, then AFAIK you only installed build dependencies. I don't think they will do any harm (aside from taking up disk space) however if you're determined to remove them see [How can I remove all build dependencies for a particular package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180504/how-can-i-remove-all-build-dependencies-for-a-particular-package)